# When do you actually use multiple foreign keys?

Tags: sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I want to create tables where one has multiple foreign keys of the other. Then I want relationships between the two using the foreign_keys argument.

```
class Trial(SurrogatePK, Model):

    __tablename__ = 'trials'
    challenges = relationship('Challenge', foreign_keys='[Challenge.winner_id, '
                              'Challenge.loser_id]')

class Challenge(SurrogatePK, Model):

    __tablename__ = 'challenges'
    winner_id = reference_col('trials')
    winner = relationship('Trial', back_populates='challenges',
                          foreign_keys=winner_id)

    loser_id = reference_col('trials')
    loser = relationship('Trial', back_populates='challenges', 
                         foreign_keys=loser_id)
```

This doesnt work because sqlachemy gets two foreign_keys and gives an error for that.
The way to make it work is with a primaryjoin:

```
class Trial(SurrogatePK, Model):

    __tablename__ = 'trials'
    challenges = relationship('Challenge', primaryjoin=
                              'or_(Trial.id==Challenge.winner_id,'
                              'Trial.id==Challenge.loser_id)')
```

Now, the thing that I want to ask is. When should I actually use multiple foreign keys in the foreign_keys argument. It's got to be plural for a reason right?
In the entire documentation I can't find a singel case where they are actually using multiple foreign keys.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.foreign_keys) part of the docs?

Comment: I have, it doesn't answer my question

Comment: I think you should define two relations, challenges_losers & challenges_winners

Comment: Why should I do that?

Comment: In your working example it basically contains both foreign_keys. You don’t write it because it’s populated by SQLAlchemy. In your first example it’s unclear how to join the relationship.

Comment: Im not exactly sure what you mean, but it has made me realize something. In the non-working example, it could never work, because if I would add a challenge to the challenges, then sqlalchemy can't know if it should be stored in the loser_id or winner_id.

Comment: But I'm still wondering in what case I can actually use multiple foreign keys